# restore backup full content or just specific folders

Tags: plugins, backup

I have a .wpress backup, I extracted it and saw all the data, I am wanting to upload to the server this backup, but I just need to restore a specific plugin, should I restore all wp content or all plugins folder or can i just update the specific plugin inside plugins folder does a plugin can affect other? I ask this because I did a roll back of Elementor plugin and damaged the UI and now I want to restore to the backup version If I just upload this specific plugin will be enough or is a bad practice, does rolling back a plugin can affect others or them are all independents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to restore a specific plugin, then you could just restore that one folder.

The only extra item to be concerned about is any database changes made with the different version of plugin. You will want to check the plugin version in your backup and compare to the LIVE version in your site. Check the readme file for changes. if there are no database changes, then you are likely OK to restore just the files.

Most likely, when you restored Elementor, it had database changes too. For that software, it's best to go to their Tools section and use their "Rollback" feature to restore a previous version as that will do both files & database changes for Elementor and Elementor Pro.